# ¿Debemos modificar las instrucciones de uso de [apache]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, wiki-de-etiqueta, extracto-de-etiquetas

EDIT: Ya se ha cambiado el texto de la etiqueta.

He visto que la etiqueta [apache](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) se usa a veces junto a otra etiqueta de la fundación Apache. Por ejemplo, preguntas sobre Tomcat se crean con las etiquetas [`[apache] y [tomcat]`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache+tomcat).

Un par de ejemplos recientes de preguntas con múltiples etiquetas:

- [Apache ProxyPass to Tomcat, timeout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302478/apache-proxypass-to-tomcat-timeout)
- [¿Cómo se crean "alias" en Apache Tomcat?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306375/c%C3%B3mo-se-crean-alias-en-apache-tomcat)

[El texto descriptivo de la etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/apache/info) ahora mismo es:

> Utilice esta etiqueta para cuestiones de programación relacionadas con el Servidor Apache HTTP (Apache HTTP Server)

El problema que veo es que si alguien está suscrito a la etiqueta [apache](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) porque quiere aprender o aportar sobre el servidor web, se va a encontrar resultados de otros productos que no esté interesado o que no pueda aportar mucho sobre ellos.

En el sitio inglés la etiqueta tiene [este texto descriptivo](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/apache/info):

> Use this tag (along with an appropriate programming-language tag) for programming questions relating to the Apache HTTP Server. Do not use this tag for questions about other Apache Foundation products. Note that server configuration questions are usually a better fit on https://serverfault.com

Entiendo que han introducido estas notas para evitar el problema mencionado.

Así que mis preguntas son:

- ¿Qué os parecería cambiar la etiqueta para indicar que no se debe usar para preguntas que no sean sobre el servidor web de Apache?
- La última frase del texto inglés recomienda hacer la pregunta en [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com). ¿Qué os parecería incluir también este texto en la etiqueta, ya que básicamente estamos redirigiendo a un usuario que está usando un sitio en español a un sitio en el que tendrá que leer y preguntar en inglés?

Comment: Mis respuestas son: _- estoy de acuerdo_ y _- es complicado dado que es un sitio en inglés, yo no lo añadiría a la indicación de uso_

Comment: y que tal si cambiamos la etiqueta tomcat a apache_tomcat, y apache en realidad no se deberia usar salvo esten hablando de apache 1, el que normalmente hablan en las preguntas es apache2

Comment: @JackNavaRow, lo único que veo ahi es que si se llama a cada proyecto de apache con el prefijo apache_, si se hace para uno, habría que preguntarse si se debería hacer para el resto de proyectos y hay bastantes (http://www.apache.org/index.html#projects-list). A cuento de esto también me he fijado que hay una duplicidad con [tag:apache-cordova] y [tag:cordova]

Comment: A la vuelta del fin de semana publico el cambio si no hay más discusión sobre este tema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se ha modificado la etiqueta [apache](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) para que tenga [este texto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/apache/info):

> Utilice esta etiqueta para cuestiones de programación relacionadas con el Servidor Apache HTTP (Apache HTTP Server). Por favor, no utilice esta etiqueta para preguntas sobre otros productos de la fundación Apache.

Comment: Genial por plantearlo, buscar soluciones y finalmente implementarlas :)